# Matploblib imshow with custom colormaps (e.g. custom map, and custom scaling)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I've twisted myself around in trying to get imshow to plot data with a custom 'enhancement' (e.g. custom colormap).  I'm using a pre-determined coloring scheme, with a pre-determined scale, so I didn't come up with this crazy color/scale combination.

In short, I have a hex list of the colors I need to make the custom colormap, with the associated scale:

```
colors = ['#000000', '#060606', '#4b4b4b', '#707070', '#404040', '#707070', '#a0a0a0', '#000000', '#ffffff', '#888888', '#585858']

scale = [0, 59, 68, 97, 175, 188, 199, 209, 215, 221, 226]
```

As you can see, my scale isn't close to linear.  It's made up ad hoc, it seems.

Anyway, I'm still a bit new to matplotlib, and I'm have a hard time seeing the forest through the trees with how to get a:
  1) custom colormap, given its not linear or exponential
  2) map that custom colormap to this stupid irregular scale
  3) plot it in imshow

For the record, I'm using basemap to plot coastlines/countries etc under the image (it's a weather satellite image for those who care).

I started with using colors.ListedColorMap, but that gave me a evenly spaced colormap.  Needless to say, the block of code below (shortened for brevity) produces an evenly scaled colormap that repeats itself several times on the image, making the image unreadable :

```
enhancement_colormap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
m = Basemap(projection='geos', lon_0=sat_lon, resolution='i', area_thresh=1000, llcrnrx=X1.min(),llcrnry=Y1.min(), urcrnrx=X1.max(),urcrnry=Y1.max())
m.imshow(np.flipud(data1),cmap=enhancement_colormap)
```

Any ideas on how to combine the customized colormap and scale, and get it to plot in imshow?  Apologies if my frustration is obscuring a simple answer from me at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a discrete colormap (i.e. only those colors from the list being present in the map) or some continuous map with gradients between the colors? Also, is the data to show strictly inside the range [0,226]? In short, given the list and scale, what would be the desired output?

Comment: Good question.  Apparently, I want only those 11 colors, using no gradients.  The data actually ranges from about 0-250 (the top of the range seems to fluctuate a bit), with the first color #000000 representing the 0-59 range, and #585858 for anything 226+.  I should have clarified that.  Apologies!  (Although a gradient map would look better...are the methods of doing them both all that different?)

Answer (score 1):

So you need to specify the intervals of the colors. This can easily be done using a `BoundaryNorm` but would require to know the maximum value to colormap.

So say the maximum value is 250, we can add this to the `scale`, such that this list now denotes the interval boundaries. Hence, `scale` has one element more than `colors`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

colors = ['#000000', '#060606', '#4b4b4b', '#707070', '#404040', '#707070', 
          '#a0a0a0', '#000000', '#ffffff', '#888888', '#585858']

scale = [0, 59, 68, 97, 175, 188, 199, 209, 215, 221, 226, 250]

cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm=matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(scale, len(colors))

data = np.atleast_2d(np.arange(250))
plt.imshow(data, aspect="auto", cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Perfect.  While I'm at it, is there a way to 'gradient' the uneven scaling between scale values?  I've done this before with numpy linspace in contourf...I'm just getting confused on how to properly import that logic into imshow.....

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what "to 'gradient' the uneven scaling between scale values" would mean.